# Remove $ type and Id properties from existing Json stream?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am serializing a complex object with following code:

```
var customerResultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customerResult, 
    CustomerSettings.GetDefaultSettings());
```

The `customerResultJson` is now having `$type` and `$id` showing because of this. I don't have control over `CustomerSettings.GetDefaultSettings` as it's from a different project dll. I want to remove those property types. how can I achieve this? Tried following but `newCustomerResultJson` nested objects still maintain the type and ids.

```
var customerDeserializeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(customerResultJson,
    new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None, Formatting = Formatting.Indented});

var newCustomerResultJson= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customerDeserializeObject, 
    new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None, Formatting = Formatting.Indented});
```

Sample customerResultJson :

```
{
   "$id": "1",
   "$type": "Customer.CustomerAddress, Customer.CustomerAddress.Common, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f291d57f641e84e4",
   "FlatRate": 29.65,
   "AmountFinanced": 12402.2,
   "AmountUsed": 12302.2,
   "TotalPayment": 0,
   "CustomerAddress": {
      "$id": "2",
      "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Customer.Customerbject, Drive.Framework, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f291d57f641e84e4]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
      "Items": {
         "$id": "3",
         "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Customer.Customerbject, Customer.Framework, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f291d57f641e84e4]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
         "$values": []
      },
      "Added": {
         "$id": "4",
         "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Customer.Customerbject, Customer.Framework, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f291d57f641e84e4]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
         "$values": []
      },
      "Removed": {
         "$id": "5",
         "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Customer.Customerbject, Customer.Framework, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f291d57f641e84e4]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
         "$values": []
      }
   }
   }
```

Comment: So you basically need to use all the settings from `CustomerSettings.GetDefaultSettings()` **except `TypeNameHandling` and `PreserveReferencesHandling`**, which you need to ignore?  But if re-serializing `customerDeserializeObject` without those settings is resulting in `"$id"` and `"$type"` properties being emitted, then those settings can't be the cause, can they?

Comment: Yes dbc.That is my understanding as I dont own that code but is working for my serilazation intially.

Comment: But re-serializing without those settings is still causing  `"$id"` and `"$type"` properties to be emitted?  If so, can you share a [mcve]?  Or do you not understand why those properties are still being emitted, and need help understanding why?

Comment: Not sure what the $type is from, but the $id might be from this: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm

Comment: dbc, I have edited the question for sampe Json

Comment: When deserializing, specity your type: `DeserializeObject<Customer>(customerResultJson, ...`. It gives you concrete type instead of `object`. Then serialization with proper settings gives you desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I achieved my objective: Posting here so that it may help someone.

```
 JObject respJObject = JObject.Parse(JsonResult);
  respJObject.Descendants().OfType<JProperty>().Where(attr => attr.Name.StartsWith("$type")).ToList().ForEach(attr => attr.Remove());
```

The above line removes type from nested properties as well.